# TypeScript add Object to array with push

Tags: arrays, typescript

I would just  like to add an object of an class (Pixel) to an array.

```
export class Pixel {
  constructor(x: number, y: number) {}
}
```

The class has the following attribute:

```
pixels: Pixel[] = [];
```

The following code looks logical for me, but does not push the actual objects to my array pixels.

```
this.pixels.push(new Pixel(x, y));
```

Only this works:

```
var p = {x:x, y:y};
this.pixels.push(p);
```

Could anybody explain me why the above statement does not work?

Comment: your code is fine and is working well when I try it.  It must be something else that causes the problem. Please include the real code that is problematic along with the error message

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If your example represents your real code, the problem is not in the `push`, it's that your constructor doesn't do anything.

You need to declare and initialize the `x` and `y` members.

Explicitly:

```
export class Pixel {
    public x: number;
    public y: number;   
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Or implicitly:

```
export class Pixel {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed the constructor was wrong. IMO the IDE could give me a warning on this issue, because I doubt anybody want that behavior. :-)

Comment: If you want to use ES6 version filter like:  this.pixels.filter(e => e.x === value); you'll need to use the 'Explicitly' model as shown.

Comment: @phanf I don't think that's correct, the generated javascript [is identical](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20ExplicitPixel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20y%3A%20number%3B%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20ImplicitPixel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20x%3A%20number%2C%20public%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2):

```
class PushObjects {
    testMethod(): Array<number> { 
        //declaration and initialisation of array onject
        var objs: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,7];
        //push the elements into the array object
        objs.push(100);
        //pop the elements from the array
        objs.pop();
        return objs;
    }   
}

let pushObj = new PushObjects();
//create the button element from the dom object 
let btn = document.createElement('button');
//set the text value of the button
btn.textContent = "Click here";
//button click event
btn.onclick = function () { 

    alert(pushObj.testMethod());

} 

document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: Hello, please learn how to format code, it's easy. Also would be nice to add some comment, for example, what Your code does.

Comment: better to use const than var